# How to know args of launched program (process)?

Tags: windows, winapi

How to know programatically (win api) the list of args, given via command line at program launching?

Comment: Depends on how the app starts.  But `GetCommandLine`  should be available either way

Comment: Sure, I didn't say. It would be obtaining args of processes in system

Comment: You mean, of *other* programs?

Answer (score 5):

To get the command line from an external process using the WinAPI, you must access the [PEB (Process Environment Block)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa813706%28VS.85%29.aspx) of the application. To get the PEB you can use the [`NtQueryInformationProcess`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms684280%28VS.85%29.aspx) function or you can use the [`Win32_Process`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa394372%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) WMI class and the `CommandLine` property.  You can find samples for these two methods on this article ["Two ways to get the command line of another process"](http://theroadtodelphi.wordpress.com/2011/07/20/two-ways-to-get-the-command-line-of-another-process-using-delphi/#comments). Also check this article ["How do I get the command line of another process?"](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2009/11/25/9928372.aspx) from Raymond Chen which provides very important information about the reliability of the Command Line buffer.

Comment: Thank you. Hm, NtQueryInformationProcess is not public so they [microsoft] say to use another public functions. But there is not function to obtain process info.

Comment: What do you mean "NtQueryInformationProcess is not public"?  Yes, it is. It is exported from ntdll.dll, use `LoadLibrary()` and `GetProcAddress()` to access it, like the [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms684280.aspx) says.